# Write a function body that can get the screen size and drag on the screen relatively

Tags: java, android, function, screen-resolution

I have many android devices of different screen sizes. I want to make sure that whatever i write the script it should draw the same thing across all the android devices independent of the screen size. So for this I have one relative method as follows:-

```
 public void dragRel(int relative) {

 }
```

Where Rel = relative terms, here screen's width and height are both '1' and a location can be expressed by fractions of 1. And so the middle of the screen is always (0.5,0.5).

How do i write a function body that can get the screen size and drag on the screen relatively.

Comment: I understand your question, and am working on this myself, but what have you tried at this point?

Comment: @trumpetlicks i am still working on it....
i was planning to add getbounds.width(); and getbounds.Height();
and then working on the mathematical formula.

Comment: I'm curious to see what answers you get here.

Comment: I can tell you that screen resolution alone wont do it, you have to correlate screen resolution to physical space.  When you say you want the "same thing" across devices, do you mean you want it to look physical size the same, only resolution wise the same, what???

Comment: It should look same(resolution size) across all the devices. SO i.e. if a device is (480 * 800) then (480 * 800) should be equal to (0.4 * 0.4) in relative terms.

Comment: if your extending a view you can use http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View.html#onSizeChanged(int, int, int, int) and make fractions of width and height for your drawing, im not sure if thats what your asking

Comment: protected void onSizeChanged (int w, int h, int oldw, int oldh) override that in your view

Comment: @trumpetlicks here is the solution...
      public void dragRel(Point relative) throws UiObjectNotFoundException {
        Point realCoord = new Point();
        realCoord.x = relative.x * getBounds().width();
        realCoord.y = relative.y * getBounds().height();
        dragPix(realCoord);
    }

Comment: I think at this point you really need to also post more of your relevant code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In general what you want to do is:

1. Query the device for it's physical dimensions.
2. Query the device for it's resolution dimensions.
3. figure out what a single pixel's PHYSICAL width and height are.
4. Define your items' sizes physically
5. when you have done this, then when you go to draw, the pixel dimensions of any object become:

   - objPixWide = objPhysWide * pixelWidthPhysical
   - objPixHigh = objPhysHigh * pixelHeightPhysical

If you have these numbers, now your relative values are simply:

- objPixWide / screenResolutionWidth
- objPixHigh / screenResolutionHeight

Comment: @user3334957 - I think this works for you IFF I understand what you are trying to accomplish.  2 screens can be same physical size, but different DPI and an object will be smaller on one screen than another.  2 screens may be different physical size but SAME DPI and one will look larger than another.  My answer normalizes objects based upon PHYSICAL size so that any object will look physically the same size on all screens regardless of screen size or resolution.

Comment: public void dragRel(Point relative) throws     UiObjectNotFoundException {
    Point realCoord = new Point();
    realCoord.x = relative.x * getBounds().width();
        realCoord.y = relative.y * getBounds().height();
        dragPix(realCoord);
    }